how to change "Link In"/"Link Out" Node line length
I don't know if this is even possible.  When using a Link In or Link Out node, it has a tail with a label going to the linked node on the other side.  It's really useful because when linking between flows,  you can just click on that label and go to the linked node.  However, the tail between the link node and the label you can click on is annoyingly long.  Does anyone know if there's a setting somewhere that can adjust the length of that tail to make the label closer to the node?
Seems trivial, but sometimes I start a flow with a link in node, and I have to set all the nodes farther from the left side of the screen so I can still click on that link if I want to.  Here's an example of what I'm talking about, you can see that the node sits pretty far away from the side so when I click on it the link is clickable:



No, this is not configurable (also did you mean to end the question mid sentence?)
